# Subject/verb agreement when a title ends in a plural

Tags: verb-agreement, proper-nouns

1) "The book 'The Three Musketeers' is a wonderful example of..." Here we have a proper noun, a title that happens to end in a plural, and I have no sense that the verb should be plural. "Musketeers"/is seems proper/natural/correct, and 'are' not at all.

However, such certainty begins to wane in other examples: 2) "'The Heidi Chronicles' is a wonderful example of..." doesn't completely shake my confidence, but it moves the needle, at least a little bit. But, practically speaking, I wouldn't have a second thought about correcting a student who used 'are' instead of 'is'.

Here's the one that really bothers me: 3a) " 'The Basement Tapes' are a wonderful example of..." I don't think this sounds any less proper/natural/correct than 3b) " 'The Basement Tapes' is..." In fact, 3a seems less awkward than 3b.

Why?

Answer (score 4):

If you're to speak/write English well, you'll need to trust that certain constructions are correct, though your intuition currently causes you to feel differently. One that you should definitely trust is subject-verb agreement. To follow this rule, you need to be aware of what the subject of the sentence actually is.

"The book 'The Three Musketeers' is a wonderful example of.. is actually

> The book is a wonderful example of.. (or *The Three Musketeers* is a wonderful example of...)

If you say "'The Three Musketeers' *are*...", you're talking about Athos, Porthos, and Aramis.

The same is true of all the other plural proper noun titles.

> - *The Basement Tapes* **is** a great collection...
> - *The Basketball Diaries* **is** a harrowing look at drug addiction...

Perhaps you are having doubts because you are identifying the subject incorrectly. *The Basketball Diaries* is a movie (singular), not a set of diaries. *The Basement Tapes* is an album (a singular noun which happens to be a collective noun as well), not a group of individual tapes. (The individual songs on an album are *tracks*.)

> *The Basketball Diaries* and *Trainspotting* **are** powerful movies dealing with drug addiction.

Comment: Excellent explanation. Meanwhile, I quite often hear confusion even among NPR journalists regarding the true number of the subject of a sentence. (Even professional communicators have their weak spots.  :-)

Comment: Yes. Another example: '_The Chronicles of Narnia_ is a series of seven high fantasy novels by author C.S. Lewis.' [Wikipedia]. And a related one: He was a servant of _He who must not be named_.